# Trying to pass user input into a simple shell that I am creating

Tags: c, shell

I am creating a simple shell. User enters a system call, I fork and call execvp on the child process for whatever command the user entered. I debugged and it seems the args that I am passing to the execvp is not correct. Could someone help me out, I am new to C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXLINE 80
int main(void){
    char *args[MAXLINE/2 + 1]; 
    char buf[MAXLINE/2 + 1];

    int should_run = 1; 
    printf("Shell\n");
    fgets(buf, MAXLINE,stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
    int i=0;
    char *token;
    token = strtok(buf," ");
    while(token != NULL){
        args[i++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
    }

    while(should_run){
        if(strcmp(args[0],"exit") == 0){
            should_run = 0;
            break;
        }
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();

        //child process
        if(pid == 0){
            execvp(args[0],args);
        }
        else{

            wait(0);
            //Also how do I make it so that the program starts from top again, meaning it lets the user enter another system call
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The [execvp man page says](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) this regarding the second parameter: "The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `execvp` function requires that you NULL-terminate the list itself.  Currently, your tokenising loop does not put a `NULL` on the last token, and so the behaviour is undefined (you never initialised your array).

A compact (but not very pretty) solution is to rearrange your loop like this:

```
int i = 0;
char *token;
do {
    token = strtok( i == 0 ? buf : NULL," ");
    args[i++] = token;
} while( token != NULL );
```

Comment: what would be a prettier solution?

Comment: In my opinion "prettier" is to not use branching inside the loop.  But that's subjective.  This ought to do the job just fine.